# Перенос поля SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, pdo

У меня есть БД с таблицей. Возьмем к примеру "un_names". Таблица " registered_names". Все пока понятно. Кто - то регистрируеться, он в таблице "un_names " , после потверждения в " registered_names ". 
Вот такой запрос использую я, для опеределения кто регнулся, берем запрос на рандомную выборку.

Вставляем в "registered_names" 1 рандомное имя из "un_names" :

```
INSERT INTO registered_names 
  SELECT DISTINCT * FROM un_names 
    WHERE un_name.name = name ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 1
```

Выводим кто регнулся :

```
echo $row["name"]." Перенесен ";
```

И удаляем из старой таблицы :

```
DELETE FROM un_names WHERE id = un_name.name = name
```

PHP код

```
$stmt = $db->query(' INSERT INTO registered_names SELECT DISTINCT * FROM names WHERE names.name= name ORDER BY ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 1 ');
echo $row["name"]." Перенесен ";
$stmt = $db->query(' DELETE FROM names WHERE names.name= name ');
```

Скажите пожалуйста, почему не работает? Получаю такую ошибку

> - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error

Comment: 1) у вас сервер один или он реплицирован? Если реплицирован, лучше вообще не использовать INSERT ... SELECT ... 2) У вас эти запросы обернуты в транзакцию. 3) Не можете привести полный текст ошибки?

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю что значение поля, по которому делаются операции, находится в переменной `$row["name"]`. Но оно никак не используется в запросах к базе. О чем вероятней всего и уведомляет mysql в своих сообщениях об ошибках.

Переменную надо передать в запрос. И лучше это сделать следующим образом

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO registered_names SELECT DISTINCT * FROM names WHERE names.name=? ORDER BY ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
if ( $stmt->execute(array($row["name"])) ) {
  echo $row["name"]." Перенесен ";
  $stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM names WHERE names.name=?');
  $stmt->execute(array($row["name"]));
}
```